# Blaze Persistence skip null parameters in where expression

Tags: blaze-persistence

is there a way to skip null parameters in where expression? Let's suppose I have the following code:

```
Boolean deleted = null;
var criteriaBuilder = cbf.create(em, MyClass.class)
                 .where("deleted").eq(deleted);
```

I would want to skip the evaluation of "deleted" when the deleted variable is null. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks
euks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually done by conditionally adding the predicate like this:

```
var criteriaBuilder = cbf.create(em, MyClass.class);
if (deleted != null) {
    criteriaBuilder.where("deleted").eq(deleted);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used this strategy.

Comment: Hello @Christian Beikov.
Can you please check this question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69253704/is-blaze-persistence-querydsl-integration-support-projections

How I can get the total count for this query even I used pagination?