# Is Blaze-Persistence Querydsl integration support projections?

Tags: java, spring, querydsl, blaze-persistence

How to use Projections with Blaze-Persistence Querydsl?

And in bellow example when criteria.getEmail() give me NullPointerException.
So How I can overcome NullPointerException for more wheres?

```
cbf.create(em, WalletReportDto.class)
                .fromSubquery(WalletCTE.class, "offerCTO").from(TenantBalanceOffers.class, "tbo")
                .bind("walletId").select("tbo.wallet.id")
                .bind("amount").select("SUM(tbo.amount)")
                .groupBy("tbo.wallet.id").end()

                .joinOn(TenantWallet.class, "tw", JoinType.INNER)
                .onExpression("offerCTO.walletId = tw.id")
                .end() //

                .select("MIN(tw.createdDate)", "fromtDate").select("MAX(tw.createdDate)", "toDate")

                .select("tw.customer.email", "email")
                .select("sum(offerCTO.amount)").where("tw.customer.email").eq(criteria.getEmail())

                .groupBy("tw.id")

                .getResultList();
```

Comment: Projections support was intended yes. Can you please share the stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: Thanx  @Jan-Willem Gmelig Meyling   

But the result is 

[
                1,
                "2021-08-25T20:29:41.478+00:00",
                "2021-08-25T20:29:41.478+00:00",
                "test@domain.ya",
                10.0,
                20.0,
                0.0
            ]
Why not field: value?

Comment: Ignore NPE.
I resolved it from this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67295962/blaze-persistence-skip-null-parameters-in-where-expression?rq=1
But give me advice on how to make query return data as {Field: Value} not value only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Blaze-Persistence Querydsl integration to use Querydsl projections with Blaze-Persistence's query features.

```java
List<WalletReportDto> result = new BlazeJPAQuery<>(em, cbf)
    .from(new BlazeJPAQuery<>()
          .from(QTenantBlanceOffers.tenantBlanceOffers)
          .bind(QWalletCTE.walletCTE.walletId, QTenantBlanceOffers.tenantBlanceOffers.wallet.id)
          .bind(QWalletCTE.walletCTE.amount, QTenantBlanceOffers.tenantBlanceOffers.amount.sum())
    , QWalletCTE.walletCTE)
    .innerJoin(QTenantWallet.tenantWallet)
    .on(QTenantWallet.tenantWallet.id.eq(QWalletCTE.walletCTE.walletId))
    .transform(Projections.bean(
        WalletReportDto.class,
        QTenantWallet.tenantWallet.createdDate.min(),
        QTenantWallet.tenantWallet.createdDate.max(),
        QTenantWallet.tenantWallet.customer.email,
        QWalletCTE.walletCTE.id
    )
```

Comment: I don't know why fromSubquery() method was not found.

Comment: Should be just `from`, I've updated teh answer.